# get the first line of text inside a tag using webscraping

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, data-extraction

I need to get the first line of text inside a tag using python code for web scraping.

expexted output : 22 September 1995

The code html goes like this

```
<div class="txt-block">
<h4 class="inline">Release Date:</h4> 22 September 1995 (USA)
<span class="see-more inline">
<a href="releaseinfo?ref_=tt_dt_dt">See more</a>&nbsp;»
</span></div>
```

my code to get the data is

```
soup.find('div', {"class": "txt-block"}).text
```

output is: Release Date: 22 September 1995 (USA) See more

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do this way

```
text = soup.find('h4').next_sibling
text.replace('(USA)','')
```

or

```
text = soup.find('h4',{'class','inline'}).next_sibling
text.replace('(USA)','')
```

Than you can use regex to exclude parenthesis `(USA)` like word from text.

using regex to remove a specific word from a string

```
text = soup.find('h4',{'class','inline'}).next_sibling
import re
text = re.sub(r'\s\(.+\)','',text)
```

That will remove any other parenthesis included word from that string.